# Linnear Regression: How to prove that regression coefficients can be writed in terms of correlation?

Tags: statistics, regression, least-squares, linear-regression

I was wondering if you guys can help me with this one.

Let $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ variables such that $X_{1}\sim N(0,1)$ and $X_{2}\sim N(0,1)$. Then, the linear model regression goes as follow, $Y=X\beta$ where $X=[X_{1} X_{2}]$ and $\beta=[\beta_{1},\beta_{2}]^{t}$.

If $r_{12}=Cor(X_{1},X_{2})$ and $r_{jy}=Cor(X_{j},Y)$.

We have that, $$\beta=\frac{1}{1-r_{12}^{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&-r_{12}\\
-r_{12}&1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
r_{1y}\\
r_{2y}
\end{pmatrix}$$

How can we prove this?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model is $y  = \beta_1 X_{1} + \beta_2 X_{2}$. Recall that $$ 
corr(X,Y)= \frac{\mathbb{E}(X-\mathbb{E}X)(Y-\mathbb{E}Y)}{\sigma_X^2 \sigma_Y^2},
$$
in our case 
$$
corr(X,Y)= \frac{\mathbb{E}(X_1Y)}{1^2 \times 1^2}= \mathbb{E}(X_1Y) = r_{1y}.
$$
Now, note that
$$
\beta = ( \mathbb{E}(XX^T) )^{-1}\mathbb{E}(X^Ty) 
$$ 
where, 
$$
\mathbb{E}(X ^ T y) = [\mathbb{E}(X_1y), \mathbb{E}(X_2y)] ^ T = [r_{1y}, r_{2y} ]^T.
$$
and 
$$
( \mathbb{E}(XX^T) )^{-1} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{E}(X_1^2) & \mathbb{E}(X_1 X_2) \\
\mathbb{E}(X_2 X_1) & \mathbb{E}(X_2 ^ 2) \\
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & r_{12} \\
r_{21} & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
=
\frac{1}{1 - r_{21}^2}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & - r_{12} \\
- r_{21} & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Properties used: $\mathbb{E} ( X_i^2 ) = \operatorname{var} (X_i) = 1$, $i=1,2$,  and $\mathbb{E}(X_1 X_2) = r_{12}$ where $r_{12} = r_{21}$.